# asp.net mvc5 invite facebook friends using OWIN

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

As per the topic above, I would like to know how to implement facebook invitation using OWIN in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Owin will allow you to authenticate the user at the external provider and give you the capability to get an access token in which you can store. As far as the invitation is concerned you most likely need to use the C# facebook api or write your own  "Facebook" graph wrappers.